# show only tags of an xml document on the command line

Tags: shell, xml

Is there a command line command or utility I can use to show only the tag structure of an xml document? I looked at xmllint but I didn't see a switch to do it. For a structure like

```
<tag1><tag2><tag2-5>value1</tag2-5><tag3>value2</tag3></tag2></tag1>
```

I want to see

```
<tag1><tag2><tag2-5></tag2-5><tag3></tag3></tag2></tag1>
```

Comment: Is it always that trivial? Will you have attributes on the tags?

Comment: Yeah, it is always that trivial. I'm not worried about the properties. There is a lot of actual data that I don't need to see, I just need the tag names to build xpath expressions.

Answer (score 2):

I think (but am not at all sure) that you can get away with just stripping out the characters between `>` and `<` globally:

```
sed 's/>[^<]*</></g' /path/to/file.xml
```

Comment: This catches simple cases, but not `<foo>hello↲world</foo>` where `↲` is a newline. Nor CDATA (if you have this, you [need a real HTML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)).

Comment: Crap :S The content data I want to filter out is a lot of text with newlines :(

Answer (score 1):

The following `xmlstarlet` command would set the values of each text-only node in your document to an empty string. It would additionally preserve whitespaces between nodes (not do pretty-printing) and omit adding an XML declaration tag (`<?xml...?>`):

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -P -O -u '//child::text()' -v '' file.xml
```

Given your example document in `file.xml`, this would produce

```xml
<tag1><tag2><tag2-5></tag2-5><tag3></tag3></tag2></tag1>
```

Without the `-P` and `-O` options:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tag1>
  <tag2>
    <tag2-5></tag2-5>
    <tag3></tag3>
  </tag2>
</tag1>
```

---

One could also use

```bsh
xmlstarlet ed -d '//child::text()' file.xml
```

to *delete* the values rather than setting them to an empty string, but that would generate nodes with no value (rather than nodes with an empty value):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tag1>
  <tag2>
    <tag2-5/>
    <tag3/>
  </tag2>
</tag1>
```

Adding the `-P` and `-O` options would generate

```xml
<tag1><tag2><tag2-5/><tag3/></tag2></tag1>
```

---

Depending on what it is that you *actually* want to do, one could use the `el` (`elements`) sub-command of `xmlstarlet` to get another representation of the document structure:

```bsh
xmlstarlet el file.xml
```

The output for your example:

```
tag1
tag1/tag2
tag1/tag2/tag2-5
tag1/tag2/tag3
```

See also `xmlstarlet el --help`.